# Relative to Java packages in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to `Xamarin` framework, and as I created a new Android Application I noticed the `MainActivity.cs` class located in the root of the project. I'm also new to C# so I don't know if all files are supposed to be on the root, but if not, will there be any issue if I organise my classes in packages/folders?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with organizing classes into folders. Namespaces are much more important than the physical location of the files, but it's good practice to have your namespaces reflect the folder hierarchy.

For example, if you create an Activies folder on the root and move MainActivity into that, the namespace in your MainActivity.cs file should be `YourAppName.Activities`.

When you add new files into an existing folder, this will be done for you, but moving existing files into a folder will require a manual refactor of the file's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java in C# you are not required to place a class in any particular file, indeed you can place a class in multiple files (this happens when you use Xaml) or more than one class in one file.

That said I would recommend you place each class in a file named after it and that you, in general, make a folder for each namespace. However I have seen some mysterious crashes and "could not find class that actually where there" related to this, so you may have to skip that if you find weird issues with Xamarin Studio.